# Show selected box in horizontal scroll box

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have horizontal scroll box i.e Row column structure in it. Thats working fine
Now I need to show selected box as well. Need to show box selected as per image i have attached which is infront after scroll.
need help in this doing this?

My html structure is like this using angular JS and ionic.

```html
<div class="row" <div class="row" style="width:100%;overflow-x:scroll;">
<div class="col col70" style="width:200px;height:150px;border:1px solid black;">

</div>
<div class="col col70" style="width:200px;height:150px;border:1px solid black;">

</div>
</div>
```

I have structure like this its look like [[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqcVc.png)

Now how I can show div is selected using javascript.

Comment: Kindly refer my attached screenshot. I have horizontal scroll div. And whichever box is infront need to show selected as per attached image. Hope you get it

Comment: You could add addEventListner to the div so that when clicked , it added a class is_focused and this class will be with red border with like 10 border-radius and so on. But the point is how will it return to its normal state after selecting another, this will be answered after you answer what exactly is this.. so i can tell you the proccess of how to achieve it.

Comment: This is just normal horizontal div. Its card structure i need to show slight part of another card as well as per my image attached. And whichever div is on front i need to show selected. So that what i want. This is mobile screen.

Answer (score 0):

If what I understood was correct, this is what you meant. If not please leave a comment.

I just made the scroll div move along adding or subtracting 5 to its css position left ever the div was scrolled.

```js
var lastX = $(".row").scrollLeft();
$(".row").scroll(function() {
  
  var position = $(".scroll-box").position();
  var position1 = $(".fa-caret-down").position();
  
  const $el = $(".row");
  let currX = $el.scrollLeft();
  
  if (currX > lastX) {
  
    $(".scroll-box").css("left", position.left + 5);
    $(".fa-caret-down").css("left", position1.left + 5);
    lastX = $el.scrollLeft();
  
  } 
  
  if (currX < lastX) {
  
    $(".scroll-box").css("left", position.left - 5);
    $(".fa-caret-down").css("left", position1.left - 5);
    lastX = $el.scrollLeft();
  
  }
  
});
```

```css
.scroll-box {

  position: fixed;
  bottom: 75px;
  left: 125px;
  
}

.fa-caret-down {
 
 position: fixed;
 left: 215px;
 bottom: 40px;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
<div class="row" style="width: 100%; overflow-x:scroll;">
<div style="width: 150%; height: 150%;">The following scroll box follows the scroller.</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="scroll-box col col70" style="width:200px;height:150px;border:1px solid black;">
</div>
<i class='fas fa-caret-down' style='font-size:48px;color:red'></i>
</div>
```

Comment: No there are multiple columns in row. You just have taken single one. So on scrolling horizontally one by one need to select. Refer my attached screenshot. Need to display some part of the next box. On start first slide will get displayed and selected and part of second one is visible. When we slide second box that will get highlighted and some part of third is visible. and goes on.

Comment: Oh ok, I will try to do that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this.

```css
div.scrollmenu {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.scrollmenu a {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div.scrollmenu a:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollmenu">
  <a>A</a>
  <a>B</a>
  <a>C</a>
  <a>D</a>
  <a>E</a>
  <a>F</a>
  <a>G</a>
  <a>H</a>
  <a>I</a>
  <a>J</a>
  <a>K</a>
  <a>L</a>
  <a>M</a>
  <a>N</a>
  <a>O</a>
  <a>P</a>
  <a>Q</a>
  <a>R</a>
  <a>S</a>
  <a>T</a>
  <a>U</a>
  <a>V</a>
  <a>W</a>
  <a>X</a>
  <a>Y</a>
  <a>Z</a>
</div>
```